# Finding out the total number of email accounts in a cPanel server

Tags: linux, email

I need to find the total number of email accounts in a cPanel Linux server.

This must include only the active accounts. i.e. only those accounts whose MX is pointing to this server.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using following one liner.

```
for i in `cat /etc/localdomains`; do grep -E ^$i: /etc/userdomains ; done | sed 's/://g' | awk '{ system("cat /home/"$2"/etc/"$1"/passwd") }' 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this script which checks the users in '/etc/userdomains' and displays the count of total mail accounts in the server.

`sed "s|:||g" /etc/userdomains | awk '!/^\* nobody/{print $1, $2 | "sort | uniq" }' | awk '{print "cat /home/"$2"/etc/"$1"/passwd"}' | sh 2>/dev/null | wc -l`

but I am looking for a script which could search the /etc/localdomains.

Regards,
Ajo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
find /home*/*/etc -name passwd -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```