# How to get count of email accounts per user in cPanel?

Tags: linux, bash

This question is similar: [Finding out the total number of email accounts in a cPanel server](https://serverfault.com/questions/252986/finding-out-the-total-number-of-email-accounts-in-a-cpanel-server) which I would love to comment on, but can't because of reputation.

This one-liner works well to get a **total** count of all email accounts.

```
for i in `cat /etc/localdomains`; do grep -E ^$i: /etc/userdomains ; done | sed 's/://g' | awk '{ system("cat /home/"$2"/etc/"$1"/passwd") }' 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

How can I modify this to return a count **per** user account?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker It is actually a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is really hacked together being my first bash script, but it works for what I needed.

Create a file: `pico num_email_accounts.sh`

Copy and paste the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Return count of email accounts per cPanel user

output="User\tDomain\t# Email Accounts\n\n------------------\t---------------------------------------\t--------------------";

for i in `cat /etc/localdomains`; do
    line=`grep -E ^$i: /etc/userdomains`;
    if [ ! -z "$line" -a "$line" != " " ]; then
            re="^([^-]+): (.*)$";
            [[ $line =~ $re ]] && domain="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" && user="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
            wc="`wc -l "/home/"$user"/etc/"$domain"/passwd" 2>/dev/null`";
            re="^([^-]+) (.*)$";
            [[ $wc =~ $re ]] && count="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
            output="$output\n$user\t$domain\t$count";
    fi
done

echo -ne $output | column -s $'\t' -t;
```

Save and exit. Make the file executable: `chmod +x num_email_accounts.sh`

Run the script: `bash ./num_email_accounts.sh`